# Ultrafast photon detectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-information, quantum-optics

Are there already photon detectors that can resolve the shape of photons in the time domaine if it looks like below where the two humps are separated by a time of the order of femtoseconds?

What I know is that there are photon detectors that can resolve in the picosecond regime (see [here](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/apl/92/24/10.1063/1.2945277)). But this article is 6 years old...

What is the best resolution that is possible today?

[image]

Comment: Yes, they exist. Google with femtosecond photon detectors.

Comment: what are the typical wavelenght ? detectors are not the sames for differents wavelenght

Comment: Do you mean 'resolve the time-distribution of photon arrival' ? An individual photon has no time-shape (nor could any detector detect "parts" of a photon).

Comment: I think the OP means "resolve the shape of a narrow wavepacket", rather than a photon.  The word "photon" suffers from much misunderstanding.  On the other hand, I don't see what my interpretation of the question has to do with the double-hump figure he has drawn.  I'd ask the OP to clarify the intent of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In fact talking about photons is pointless in this context. We can just call it wave packet. I just wrote photons because for me it is important to be sure that the wave packet is just one single photon but thats unimportant here. And yes I am just wondering about the statistical shape in the time domaine. So for an experiment one has to measure the arrival time of very much wave packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With appropriate lab equipment, you can derive extremely narrow pulse shapes.  A typical setup involves splitting the incoming beam of light and interfering it with itself. By shifting one of the path lengths, you can observe the change in the diffraction pattern and calculate the pulse width.   This won't work, of course, for a single event.  For that case, as the comments suggest, track down commercial ultrafast photon detectors.

EDIT:
for those in doubt, one can purchase nanopositioners with sub-nanometer precision.
examples:  http://www.physikinstrumente.com/en/products/prdetail.php?sortnr=200500
or http://www.newport.com/store/product.aspx?id=843084&lang=1033#tab_Specifications

Comment: But resolving in the femtosecond regime requires to control the shift in the path length of the order of $10^{-7}\,\text m$. Thats not feasible, right?

Comment: @thyme  No, see edits

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer. From your links to the nanopositioners I conclude that the current boundary  to resolve the mentioned shape is reached if the distance of the two humps is in the regime of attoseconds or shorter, right? Because then the spatial distance would be of the order of $10^{-10}\,\text m$...